# AngularJS Assign an object by its property to the ng model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm kind of new to angularJS

I have code; all of it is wrong.
I'm creating a json object with options.

I have a json object called "match" with a property "lineup".

When you check the checkbox for any player, you add this player to the lineup property like:

```
lineup:[{uid:1,pos:0},{uid:2,pos:0}]
```

What I want to know is how can I assign the select to an specific item in the `lineup` array. In example, if I change the select for the player 1, then lineup would change to:

```
lineup:[{uid:1,pos:2},{uid:2,pos:0}]
```

Btw, I know I can use `ng-options` for the select directive, but this is the last code I got before coming here.

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-if="match.formation > 0">
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="p in players track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="p.lineup"
           ng-change="setLineup(p,$index)" 
           ng-disabled="match.lineup.length > 10 && (p.lineup == 0 || !p.lineup)" />
    {{p.player}}
    <select ng-model="" class="pull-right">
        <option ng-repeat="e in NotSelectedPosition() track by $index"
                value="{{e.id}}">{{$index+1+'.- '+e.name}}</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Edit:
players is a json object as well:

```
$scope.players = [{uid:1,lineup:false,name:'player1'},
                  {uid:2,lineup:false,name:'player 2'},etc
                 ];
```

formation is just an integer value

Comment: can you share complete JSON to debug easily ?

Comment: Would be sth like $scope.match={gteam1=0, gteam2=0, lineup=[{uid:1, pos:0},{uid:2,pos:0}]};

Comment: Can you share the controller as well , because there are few missing items from your post like players, formation ?

Answer (score 1):

Bind it with p.uid not p.lineup beacuse you are using ng-repeat="p in players track by $index", which means you get the objects in an array one by one.

Comment: The checkbox ngmodels works perfect with p.lineup if I check it, it adds the uid to the final json object. The problem is with the model in the select